# Mp3 streaming/downloading website - apache server memory issue

Tags: php, apache, html, audio

I have a website, in which users can upload mp3 files (uploadify), stream them using an html5 player (jplayer) and download them using a php script (www.zubrag.com/scripts/).

When a user uploads a song, the path to the audio file is saved in the database and i'm using that data in order to play and show a download link for the song. 
The problem that i'm experiencing is that, according to my host, this method is using a lot of memory on the server, which is dedicated.

Link to script: http://pastebin.com/Vus8SRa7

How should I handle the script properly? And what would be the best way to track down the problem? Any ideas on cleaning up the code?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing your files on disk (named something random [check for collisions!] or sequential, without file extension, and outside of the doc root), and only store information in your DB.  It's much easier to stream a file from disk this way than it is out of a database result.

When you retrieve an entire file's contents out of a database result, that data has to be in memory.  `readfile()` doesn't have this issue.  Use headers to return the original file name when sending the file back to the client, if you wish.

Comment: I'm storing only the file path in the database along with the artist name and other info, so when I want to stream it or download it, I request the path from the database. Is this what you meant? Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to buffer the content when you are writing binary data of the MP3 onto your HTTP output. That way you'd be saving a lot on physical and virtual memory usage.